# Which has better readability for a web article list? tiled card view or listed compact view?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

so, I'd like to create a UI design for my school website, there's one section of an article/school journalism webpage, I'm a little confused for using between tiled card view or list compact view?

Multi-column layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B420r.png

One-column layout - List View
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzk6J.png

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's hard to decide between one-column or multiple-column layouts. One of the most important goals of a good UX design is that your visitors focus more on the content, so consider your users and their actions.

Many designers use multi-column layout because it is more appealing to the eye, but also it increases the chaos on the page. Based on statistics, adults want more calmness in facing a website page (one-column), but kids want to play and be entertained so chaos isn't that bad in here (multi-column).

Also, it depends on your content. If you want to bold each of your items, one-column is really better and it prevents user miss-click. It becomes even better if you have lots of content in a list preview (such as image, notification icons and etc.).

If you have simple items without images and priority to show, multi-column is better because it lowers the scroll height and you can show more content in a viewpoint, for example, an e-commerce website or etc.